# Typescript inferring members from function factories versus classes

Tags: typescript

Using classes I can directly access members without typescript typechecker complaning but with factory functions when I use typeof, It says the property doesn't exist.

```
function serviceFunc() {
  function add(){
    //logic...
  }
  return {
    add
  }
}

class ServiceClazz{
  private val;
  
  constructor() {
    this.val = 0;
  }
  add(){
    console.log(this.val);
  }
}

const func1: typeof serviceFunc = serviceFunc();


//property add does not exist...
serviceFunc.add();

//doesn't complain about add...
const func2: ServiceClazz = new ServiceClazz();
func2.add();
```

Does that mean I have to define my serviceFunc with an interface to get typings? Seems like classes benefit in this case or am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this just a typo?  You can't write `const func1: typeof serviceFunc = serviceFunc()` for the same reason you can't write `const func2: typeof ServiceClazz = new ServiceClazz()`; a constructor is not the object it constructs, and a function is not the value it returns.  Analogously, you can't call `serviceFunc.add()` for the same reason you can't call `ServiceClazz.add()`.  If, instead, you write

```
const func1 = serviceFunc();
func1.add();
```

it will work.  If you really want to give a type annotation to `func1`, you can use [the `ReturnType<F>` utility type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#returntypetype) like this:

```
const func1: ReturnType<typeof serviceFunc> = serviceFunc();
```

which is equivalent to

```
/* const func1: {
    add: () => void;
} */
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.2.3#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAZwKYCcBuMKoGLgQAUAlIgN4BQiNioksCiAhgCaukXW08D0vAGzgBzHADoJ3GgF8pidKigh0SKjx5tWc2bMoQBzZMkQBlDNlwBhAwC8bXHgAd0MTMyipEbgQG5KciARkKHQQaDh0TjV1GigACxhkMW9EAF5EAAY-HlkNdii5HkCwZDgBVDEhYSJ4xOTmARJs2h1-YuC6QgBGAC5EACVFZTAAFQBPR1QAHigJ1DhgFHMcfEIAPjSlrBWCSFI-XgAqRHaoTsheh1pNPs5Ujcw4GFY-aURD3kp6CC6xTX3-PxWHBUMgwAByM6BAC2jgMMCQzAARnAQGdNBIxHogmdvgAmPpmbZWWz2dJgVAAd1MyxJzDsAPxf3yTSAA)

Comment: Interesting, i'll give this a try. Appreciate it.

Comment: I see, so if I was passing the serviceFunc() return value to another function, I would use the ReturnType<typeof serviceFunc>. That did it for me. Thanks a ton. I still need to go through the reference portion of typescript site. Thanks for the clarification. Cheers